# Remove parentheses around integers in a string

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to replace `(number)` with just `number` in an expression like this:

```
4 + (3) - (7)
```

It should be:

```
4 + 3 - 7
```

If the expression is:

```
2+(2)-(5-2/5)
```

it should be like this:

```
2+2-(5-2/5)
```

I tried

```
a = a.replace(r'\(\d\+)', '')
```

where `a` is a string, but it did not work. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python has a powerful module for regular expressions, `re`, featuring a substitution method:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = '2+(2)-(5-2/5)'
>>> re.sub('\((\d+)\)', r'\1', a)
'2+2-(5-2/5)'
```

Comment: @DusanMilosevic: If an answer is helpful, remember accept it.

Comment: OH, yeah, i couldn't accept it in an hor or so, and i forgot. Sorry